# How did Cooper know the quantum data is what Murph needed to solve the gravity equation?

Tags: plot-explanation, interstellar

In *Interstellar* Professor Brand reveals only to Murph (on his deathbed) that Plan A, solving the equation was 'impossible'. I am struggling to reconcile;

A) How Murph knows that it is quantum data needed to solve the equation.

B) How Cooper knows that in order to save humanity, he must send the quantum data to Murph i.e. that the solution to the equation requires quantum data.

I get that with A) Murph could join the dots and realise what to do with this data but it is B) I am more struggling with. Was this just a last Hail Mary or had he figured out himself the quantum data would solve the equation, did he have a scientific background?

In no way is this a criticism of the movie, I would just like to understand it more.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer after rewatching a selection of scenes and am posting  it for the benefit of others.

Dr. Mann tells Cooper that Professor Brand solved the equation years ago but it didn't reconcile quantum mechanics and relativity. He goes on to say you need more data... you need to see into a black hole.

Comment: Not sure why this answer received a down vote. Whether or not the question is useful isn't relevant to the answer, and this answer actually answers the question(s).

Comment: In addition to that, A) is also pretty clear. Murph is a theoretical physicist who worked with Brand on his equation for years. Of course she knows what's needed to solve it.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Yes, this is what I said in the question itself...